# Maven Tycho - Manipulate .ini file inside a jar

Tags: maven, build, jar

I am trying to change a file (preferences.ini) within a JAR in my Maven process. I already get the JAR packed and the .ini file (on root level) looks like this:

```
# Server version
version.server = 1.2.3.4
```

Now I want to change the file within the JAR (e.g. change the version to 1.2.3.4.22.11.13).

```
# Server version
version.server = 1.2.3.4.22.11.13
```

So far I have not been able to find a way. With the 'maven-replacer-plugin' the replacement should work, but not within a JAR. I also tried the 'maven-dependency-plugin' to unpack the JAR first. Unfortunately with little success.
Also i've seen [Rename files inside a jar using some maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825743/rename-files-inside-a-jar-using-some-maven-plugin), but don't think an ant task is the 'maven' way of doing this and is more like a dirty hack.

How could this be made possible within the Maven build?